# How can I enable mouse in Vim?

Tags: linux, vim

How can I use mouse with panes in vim? I tried `:set mouse=a` but it does not seem to work when 
doing `:sp` or `:vsp` or `vim -O`

Comment: At least mention the terminal you're using, and whether other mouse-based applications work in there.

Comment: @IngoKarkat:xterm?I am not sure how to give you this information

Comment: Assuming you're running VIM in a terminal (and not using the GUI by running gvim or vim -g), showing the result of `echo $TERM` might help.

Comment: @Useless:`xterm-256color`. I am running vim in a terminal

Comment: Just to clarify: the mouse works normally when you use `:set mouse=a`, and the problem only comes when you try to work with panes, correct?

Comment: @evilsoup:I can do select/copy etc with the mouse if this is what you mean.

Comment: Can you reposition the cursor? Select / copy comes from the terminal, that has nothing to do with Vim.

Comment: @IngoKarkat:Reposition the cursor via mouse.No! Can this be done? I did not know about it!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to download and install gvim.

If you are using Red Hat, Fedora or CentOS:

`sudo yum install gvim`

If you are running Ubuntu or Debian:

`sudo apt-get install gvim`

If you are running OpenSuse:

`sudo zypper install gvim`

(Run these from the terminal, of course, not from inside vim!)

If you run vim directly in xterm, rather than running gvim, then the mouse can only interact with the terminal—not with vim directly.  Using vim in xterm you can select text with the mouse, but not move the cursor, and pasting text might work unpredictably, especially if you aren't in insert mode.  gvim will prevent these problems.